# How does Inkscape make a node segment smaller symmetrically?

Tags: inkscape, vector, svg

In this [YouTube video at this point in time](https://youtu.be/iZeN1BTUz-I?t=45) the designer makes the node segment smaller symmetrically so that it stays centered by using the keyboard, but it does not show the shortcuts.

How is this done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to have the Show Transform Handles option selected in the tool controls along the top

[image]

Then use the Edit Paths by Nodes tool <kbd>F2</kbd> to select the two nodes by clicking and dragging a selection around them

Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click and drag the transform handles.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I learn something new nearly every day:

From [The Blog of the Baodad Tree website](https://baodad.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/how-to-make-a-trapezoid-in-inkscape/):

> How To Make a Trapezoid in Inkscape
>
> 1. Draw a rectangle.
> 2. Convert it to a path (Path > Object to Path)
> 3. Use the node select tool (<kbd>F2</kbd>) to select the two corners of the
>      rectangle that you want to adjust to form a trapezoid 
>      (You have to hold down the shift key to select multiple nodes).
> 4. Press the comma or period keys to move apart or bring together the nodes.